# Locating Element within the Frameset in Html using selenium Webdriver

Tags: html, xpath, selenium-webdriver, frames, frameset

I have the following html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<frameset id="mainFrameset" bordercolor="#000000" border="2" framespacing="2" frameborder="1" rows="55,*" name="mainFrameset">
<frame scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="title.jsp" name="titleFrame">
<frameset id="innerFrameset" framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="0" cols="20.0%,*" name="innerFrameset">
<frame scrolling="auto" target="mainFrame" noresize="noresize" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="dynamicContents.jsp" name="contentFrame">
<frame scrolling="auto" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="Welcome.jsp" name="mainFrame">
<html>
<head>
<title>retailJava Home</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type">
</head>
<frameset id="mainFrameset" bordercolor="#000000" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="no" rows="*,*">
<frame scrolling="auto" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="WelcomeMain.jsp" name="welcomeMain">
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to retail-j</title>
<link type="text/css" href="/rjBackOffice/stylesheets/maintenance.classic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<base target="_self">
</head>
<body text="#000000" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0">
<div id="WelcomeContainer">
<div id="HeaderLogo">
<div id="WelcomeMessages">
<span id="WelcomeMessage">Welcome to retail-j</span>
<span id="LoginInformation">You are currently logged in as BOB</span>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</frame>
<frame scrolling="auto" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="SystemManagement/InScreenApplicationAlertViewerServlet" name="alertFrame">
<html>
</frame>
</frameset>
<noframes> <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0"> Sorry your browser does not support framesets. </body> </noframes>
</html>
</frame>
</frameset>
<noframes> <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0"> Sorry your browser does not support framesets. </body> </noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

I am trying to locate the the span element with id WelcomeMessage from the above html code. I tried the following to locate

```
driver.switchTo().frame("welcomeMain");
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='WelcomeMessage']");
```

Kindly let me know how to switch between framesets/frames [in case of a complex html with convoluted frames as shown above]and locate the elements inside them.

I get the error " unable to locate element welcomeMain......"

Kindly reply to sort this , thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not a valid HTML page. There are missing nodes and there are nodes that shouldn't be there. Even only in the `welcomeMain` frame you're opening 3 divs and only closing 2. Correct all the syntactical errors and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the issue because of your webdriver control may already inside the default frame, and you may need to take the control out of all frame first before taking it to another frame.

Check whether you are able to switch to all the frames available in that page by using below code and this should be working fine.

```
    for (WebElement e :driver.findElements(By.tagName("frame")))
    {
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        driver.switchTo().frame(e);

        if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("yourElement")).isDisplayed())
        {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("yourElement")).click();
            break;
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
```